# Flutter Custom Card Widget How to draw half circular line

Tags: flutter

There is a card widget. As seen in the picture, I want lines on this card widget. But I don't know how to do this. I would be glad if you could help me with this.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved!

This Card Widget Code

```
 Container(
    height: 190.sp, //
    width: 360.sp,
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.sp),
    child: Card(
      color: Colors.orange,
      shape:
          RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0)),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            child: Transform.rotate(
              angle: -pi / 2,
              child: CustomPaint(
                painter: MyPainter(),
                child: SizedBox(width: 65, height: 65),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            child: Transform.rotate(
              angle: -pi / 2,
              child: Transform.translate(
                offset: Offset(25, 0),
                child: CustomPaint(
                  painter: MyPainter(),
                  child: SizedBox(width: 30, height: 30),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
```

THIS CUSTOM PAINTER

```
    class MyPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final redCircle = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;
    final arcRect = Rect.fromCircle(
        center: size.bottomCenter(Offset.zero), radius: size.shortestSide);
    canvas.drawArc(arcRect, 0, -pi, false, redCircle);
  }
  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(MyPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```